# Corona SDK - How can i change color text with transition?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

Can i change color of text field with transition?
I try with normal transition like this but did not work.

```
explainer = display.newText("my text", 100,100,"Hiragino Maru Gothic Pro",30)
transition.to(explainer, { time=100, color="rgba(255,0,0)" })
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Transition in Corona SDK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8425725/transition-in-corona-sdk)

Comment: no worries ;) that thread wasn't named properly...

Answer (score 1):

You really can't do this with transition.to.  You would have to do it in an enterFrame listener and increment your R, G, B values during each step.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a code that let's you make a `blink` effect. You can remove the part that changes the increment and it will work for you:

```
local min_r,min_g,min_b=100,100,255 -- Initial color
local max_r,max_g,max_b=255,255,255 -- End color
local color_steps=15 -- Adjust this to make it more fast/slow
local current_step=0
local increment=1
local step_r=(max_r-min_r)/color_steps
local step_g=(max_g-min_g)/color_steps
local step_b=(max_b-min_b)/color_steps
function blink()
  if (rowPlayerName and rowPlayerName["text"] and rowScore and rowScore["text"]) then
    rowPlayerName:setTextColor( min_r+current_step*step_r, min_g+current_step*step_g, min_b+current_step*step_b )
    rowScore:setTextColor(min_r+current_step*step_r, min_g+current_step*step_g, min_b+current_step*step_b )
    current_step=current_step+increment
    if (current_step>=color_steps) then
      current_step=color_steps-1
      increment=-increment
    elseif (current_step<0) then
      current_step=0
      increment=-increment
    end
      timer.performWithDelay(50, blink)
  end
end
blink()
```

In this case, `rowPlayerName` and `rowScore` are 2 `display.newText` that need to be changed together.

Answer (score 0):

What you could also do, is just put another object over it with different color and set its alpha to 0. Then using transition.to method change this objects alpha property to 1.